# convert byte array ending with single null byte to UTF16 encoded string

Tags: java, string, utf-16

I got a byte array which carries strings encoded in UCS-2LE, generally, the null string terminator in UCS-2LE string would be encoded as two null bytes (00 00), but sometimes there's only one as below:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Ucs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] b = new byte[] {87, 0, 105, 0, 110, 0, 0}; 
        String s = new String(b, Charset.forName("UTF-16LE"));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.getBytes()));
        System.out.println(s);
    }   
}
```

this program outputs

> [87, 105, 110, -17, -65, -67]
>   Win�

I don't know why the internal byte array for string grows and where the unknown unicode comes from. How can I eliminate it?

Comment: `getBytes()` uses the user's default Java character encoding, which is unknown to us and probably unknown to you, too. Try dumping with a known, useful character encoding for Unicode such as UTF-16 or UTF-8.

Comment: "sometimes there's only one": Can you prevent the problem upstream?

Comment: If you don't like the replacement character (�) quietly indicating the data corruption, you can configure a character decoder that throws an exception instead.

Comment: @TomBlodget Thanks for the tip. Upstream is out of my control and wasted my time!

Answer (score 1):

use an [InputStreamReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) along with the proper [Charset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) or a custom [CharsetDecoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html).

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(
   new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[]{87, 105, 110, -17, -65, -67,0,0}),
   Chaset.forName("UTF-16LE"));

Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(
   new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[]{87, 105, 110, -17, -65, -67,0,0}),
   new CharsetDecoder(Chaset.forName("UTF-16LE"),1,2){
      @Override
      protected CoderResult     decodeLoop(ByteBuffer in, CharBuffer out){
        // detect trailing zero(s) to skip them
        // maybe employ the first version to do actual conversion
      }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Would a hack to ignore a final odd-length byte help?

```
int bytesToUse = b.length%2 == 0 ? b.length : b.length - 1;
String s = new String(b, 0, bytesToUse, Charset.forName("UTF-16LE"));
```

Comment: Yep, It's a way:)